# convert graph represented by xml to visual representation

Tags: xml, graph, pentaho

I have a self generated xml, that has about 1 million nodes, and 10 million edges, and represents a graph. Since it was autogenerated, i have no idea how the graph actually looks like and thats why i would like to get a visual representation of said graph (JPG maybe?)

the xml notation is:

```
<graph>
  <node id="1">
      <edge id="2">
      <edge id="3">
      ..
      ..
      <edge id="N">
  </node>
  <node id="1">
  ..
  ..
  </node>
</graph>
```

I was thinking that this could be achieved using pentaho kettle, since i remember using it in college to parse big xmls, however how to generate the jpg is what i dont know how to do yet..

Is this a feasible task?

Can i do it with pentaho kettle? If so, How?

Is there any other tool to fullfill to do this? Which one?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advantage".

Answer (score 2):

If you generate GraphML (http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/) you can use yEd (http://www.yworks.com/en/products/yfiles/yed/) or Gephi (http://gephi.github.io/) to visualize the graph